# Problem with RegionFunction

Tags: plotting

I am experiencing a problem involving `ContourPlot`/`RegionFunction` that I can reduce to the following simple example: If I define a condition using

`reg = Abs[x] - Abs[y] >= 0 && -(1/4) + x^2 + y^2 >= 0;`

the command

`ContourPlot[..., RegionFunction->Function[{x,y}, reg]]`

does not work properly (issues a warning complaining that the function must be boolean), while the command

`ContourPlot[..., RegionFunction->Function[{x,y}, Abs[x] - Abs[y] >= 0 && -(1/4) + x^2 + y^2 >= 0]]`

works just fine. Note that in the second case, I am just copying the condition rather than using the variable reg.

Any thoughts? The issue happens in both 13 and 14 versions, and I am quite sure that in previous versions, this was not a problem (I am reusing some old code).

Comment: The reason it does not work is that "Function" has the attribute "HoldAll". Therefore, you need to write "Function[{x,y},Evaluate[reg]]"

Comment: Thank you @DanielHuber.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define `reg` as a pure function

```
reg = Abs[#1] - Abs[#2] >= 0 && -(1/4) + #1^2 + #2^2 >= 0 &;

ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  RegionFunction :> reg]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solved the problem.